The omc command of OpenModelica is not functioning
While it is possible to compile using the OpenModelica Connection Editor, when executing omc -s xxxx.mo from the command prompt, the compilation fails.
It seems that the compilation is stopping midway because xxxx_init.c does not exist.
However, even when compiling with the OpenModelica Connection Editor, it does not appear that xxxx_init.c is being generated.
Does anyone know a solution to this issue?
I would like to compile using the omc command.

I have tried on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 running on WSL, but neither of them is working properly.

-s does not compile, just generates the code, you need to do: make -f Model.makefile to build it!

Thank you very much! Thanks to you, the problem has been resolved!
